# Display Cards in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am New to Xamarin/Xamarin Forms. I am trying to create a simple screen in Android and IOS with Xamarin Forms which will display some data in the form of Cards as in the image below. The screen is passed a list of CardModel.

```
public class CardModel
{
public int Id { get; set; }
        
public string Title { get; set; }
public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

I tried to use a CollectionView to display the cards. I was able to bind data using {Binding ..}. But the screen does not look right. It just looks like a table with 2 columns and 2 rows.

Also, I wanted to use the FlexLayout instead of the Collection view. I tried a few suggestions from StackOverflow, but nothing worked for me for binding the Model through code behind.

Is there a way to bind the FlexLayout using c# code and create the below screen? If not is it possible to achieve the below using Collection view? As I mentioned at the start, I am new to Xamarin/ Xamarin Forms so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the code you wrote, a screenshot of the result, and a comment explaining why the result is not what you want.  Either CollectionView or FlexLayout should be able to do something close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jason for pointing out the lack of code. I manged to get my desired view with collectionview/grid/frame combination(and of course a bit of style).